# Concatenation inside for loop pandas - only writing out variable for last element in list

Tags: python, pandas

`list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

```
for num1 in list1:
    pd.concat([dfnew[Indexer[0]],dfnew[Indexer[num1]]],axis=1)
```

1. This returns a dataframe only for the last element in the list. How do I get dataframes for all elements in the list?
2. Ideally I would also like to assign a name to each dataframe corresponding to each element in the list?

I have considered using a for loop but got lost on how to implement it successfully.

```
def test(list1):
    for num1 in list1:
     return pd.concat([dfnew[Indexer[0]],dfnew[Indexer[num1]]],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some progress but somehow I need to automate this so that I dont have to write this line 6 times while maintaining the unique variable names.

```
for num1 in list1:
    XReal=pd.concat([dfnew[Indexer[0]],dfnew[Indexer[1]]],axis=1)
    XImag=pd.concat([dfnew[Indexer[0]],dfnew[Indexer[2]]],axis=1)
    YReal=pd.concat([dfnew[Indexer[0]],dfnew[Indexer[3]]],axis=1)
    YImag=pd.concat([dfnew[Indexer[0]],dfnew[Indexer[4]]],axis=1)
    ZReal=pd.concat([dfnew[Indexer[0]],dfnew[Indexer[5]]],axis=1)
    ZImag=pd.concat([dfnew[Indexer[0]],dfnew[Indexer[6]]],axis=1)
```